# How to set Faces Servlet mapping with security constraint

Tags: java, jsf-2

I'm developing a jpa,jsf,jaas application and now i have this trouble :

I have this security-constraint in my web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Private</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
                <http-method>GET</http-method>
                <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>          
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
<auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/badLogin.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

so every time the application starts the user will be directed to login page , but the page displays but it hasn't gone through the faces servlet and so faces components aren't rendered. This is my Faces Servlet Mapping

```
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Just make sure that the request URL matches the URL pattern of the faces servlet.

With your current setup, you've 2 options:

1. Either change

   ```html
   <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
   <form-error-page>/badLogin.xhtml</form-error-page>
   ```

   by

   ```html
   <form-login-page>/login.jsf</form-login-page>
   <form-error-page>/badLogin.jsf</form-error-page>
   ```

   so that it matches the URL pattern of the faces servlet.

   ---
2. Or, change

   ```html
   <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
   ```

   by

   ```html
   <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
   ```

   so that you never need to fiddle with virtual URLs.

Comment: Please elaborate "does not work" in smart developer's perspective instead of in dumb enduser's perspective. Is the faces servlet still not invoked (which is impossible if the solution is properly applied and thus you're not running the code you think you're running), or is it just that CSS/JS/images are not applied (which will indeed happen with your overly generic security constraint restriction on `/*`). Look in the generated HTML output and the HTTP traffic monitor to exclude the one and other.